# Make resolve in route to a reusable function

Tags: angularjs

I have a lot of the same code in the resolve function. Is it possible to make a reusable function of it and pass it to the resolve?

```
FROM THIS... 

.when('/workers', {
        resolve: {
            "check": function () {
                if (!isLoggedIn() || !isAdmin()) {
                    window.location.href = '#/about';
                }
            },
        },
        templateUrl: 'html/admin/workers.html',
        controller: 'adminWorkersController'
    })

  TO SOMETHING LIKE THIS: 

 .when('/workers', {
            resolve: myResolveFunction()
            templateUrl: 'html/admin/workers.html',
            controller: 'adminWorkersController'
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a provider for route resolve

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
        //Must be a provider since it will be injected into module.config()
        app.provider('routeResolver', function () {
            this.$get = function () {
                return this;
            };
            this.route = function () {
               var resolve = function () {
               // resolve 
               } 
              return {resolve: resolve};
           };
        });

app.config( function(routeResolverProvider) {
  .when('/workers', {
            resolve: routeResolverProvider.resolve()
            templateUrl: 'html/admin/workers.html',
            controller: 'adminWorkersController'
        })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service for reusable code. Example:

```
resolve: {
    "check": function(yourService) {//inject service
        yourService.method(); //this method of the service contains reusable code
    }
}
```